# MySQL Shopping item table with size table

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

Please offer a helping hand.

I have an item table with the following

```
item_id(pk), name, price, color
```

I then have a table for sizes

```
item_id(fk), size, count, sequence
```

I am trying to allow users to search for an item a LEFT JOIN statement

```
SELECT table.*, sizes.* FROM item LEFT JOIN sizes ON size.item_id = item.item_id
```

The issue is I need the results to not duplicate for items with multiple sizes and I also was wondering how to only display items with size counts greater than 0

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use some aggregation and group by

first only select the fields you need in the output ( for example you don't want size so don't include it )

you want a sum of the 'count' field - so use the sum function

you need to group by the fields you are not summarising

and you can exclude the zero rows by using a where clause (assuming there are no negative counts) or a having clause

```
SELECT item_id, item.name, item.price, item.color, sum(size.count) 
FROM item LEFT JOIN sizes 
where sizes.count > 0
ON sizes.item_id = item.item_id
group by item_id, item.name, item.price, item.color
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I then choose to want to search by size?

Comment: Add size into the select/group by and/or the where clause